# Makefile condition fails for defined variable

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am writing makefiles (GNU make) for an application with more than one module. More precisely, for each module, I have one makefile. In addition, I have one master makefile which call each modules' makefile. I have been trying to factor out of these makefiles several variables that are needed everywhere. I have included an `init.mk` file at the beginning of the master makefile with the following:

```
export OS = linux

ifeq ($(OS),linux)
    export SHELL := /bin/bash
else ifeq ($(OS),windows)
    export SHELL := cmd
else
    export SHELL :=
endif
```

When I run make with this, I get an Error 127 because the comparison test fails and the `SHELL` variable is set to nothing. If I add `/bin/bash` in the `else` section, make does not fails.

Why is the `OS` variable not compared properly?

Regards

Comment: Make handles `SHELL` in special ways depending on the OS, on windows for instance it might even [ignore anything you say](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Choosing-the-Shell).

Comment: Do you have any extra whitespace at the end of the `export OS = linux` line?

Comment: I have a space and a commentt

Comment: @MasScientist If you want to write an answer, I'll accept it. That was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make variable assignments strip leading spaces, but the don't strip trailing spaces: those are included in the value of the variable.

So:

```
export OS =   linux     
                   ^^^^^
```

where there are trailing whitespace, either alone or with a comment afterwards, will cause the variable to contain spaces.  For example the above assignment the value of `OS` is `linux` followed by 5 spaces, not just `linux`.

You can either be sure to avoid trailing whitespace by hand (using an editor that has a mode for editing makefiles is very helpful here) or use the `strip` function:

```
ifeq ($(strip $(OS)),linux)
    ...
```